# How to get names of objects committed in latest commit in Git

Tags: git

I am trying to get the names on objects committed in the last commit and then trying to zip all those files. i already have the archive command which will take those files and zip them.
Below command will zip all the files in the branch.

```
git archive -o update.zip HEAD
```

but if i can somehow get the command to get the list of objects commited in the last commit i can combine these two commands and zip only those objects as shown below.

```
git archive -o update.zip HEAD $(COMMAND TO GET NAME)
```

Thanks in Advance for all the help!

Answer (score 1):

```
git diff --name-only HEAD^ HEAD
```

This actually works for any diff between any two commits :

```
git diff --name-only master test
git diff --name-only 4.2.1 staging
git diff --name-only ea43c77 HEAD
# etc ...
```

---

note : this method will not enable you to differentiate between modified/added files and deleted/renamed files.

You can try the `--name-status` option, which will add a `A, M or D` in front of each filename :

```
git diff --name-status <commit1> <commit2>
```

You would then need a bit of extra processing, to split this list into "these files should be added to the zip archive", and "these files should be deleted from the target directory".

---

If your intention is to apply the modifications of this diff, you can also generate a patch file, and apply it on the target directory :

```
# inside your repo :
git diff -p HEAD^ HEAD > update.patch

# in your target directory :
patch update.patch
```

Comment: is there any way i can get a list of object names merged from Test branch to Master?